# Given Email display name not updated in outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp

I want to change my email display name which is sent by my MVC application.
actually, the email address is: sample@company.com
the default display name is: Company Sample.

Now i want to change that display name into "SomeOne" but it not works. i have tried below items,

1. Tried Email display name property:

   `MailAddress from = new MailAddress("sample@company.com", "SomeOne");`

It works fine in Gmail but in outlook, the display name not changed.

2. `MailAddress from = new MailAddress("sample@company.com", "\\SomeOne\\");`

It will change the display name in outlook but double quote(") added at the last like this 
SomeOne"

3. `objMail.From = new MailAddress("<DisplayName>EmailAddress@domain.com");`
   Not works.

Can you please provide any suggestions..?

Thanks,
Nagaraj M

Comment: Try your 2 way but with "\\SomeOne"

Comment: Just want to clarify that you are receiving the email in gmail / outlook.

Comment: @S.Petrosov i have tried that, it not works.

Comment: @MadMyche i am receiving the email in outlook. but it not works.

Answer (score 2):

Your first address is correct

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("sample@company.com", "SomeOne");
```

And I believe the third is backwards

```
//objMail.From = new MailAddress("<DisplayName>EmailAddress@domain.com"); 
  objMail.From = new MailAddress("DisplayName<EmailAddress@domain.com>");
```

Outlook presents other challenges. If the address is in your Outlook contacts it may overwrite the friendly address coming in. Same if you are sending from Outlook to a previous friendly address. In most cases clearing out the Most Recently Used (MRU) cache will take care of it. There are a few ways of doing this, some require working with the registry to find the location of the actual file

[Clearing Outlook Most Recently Used Lists](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/clearing-outlooks-most-recently-used-mru-lists/)

your first address is correc

Comment: Thanks for your response, that sender address will available in my contacts list. I couldn't delete the cache as per your suggestion. because the email sent for not only me, all the employees in our company so i can't  tell to delete the cache for all the users.

Comment: If that address is in your contact list; you will need to fix it there. The MRU cache is basically another contact list and catches those not in your Outlook Contacts. It gets added to  whenever you send an email to someone.

Comment: So if the email is in our contact then that name only displayed instead of modified display name right?
we can't resolve this

Comment: A question i really dont have answer to. If its working in gmail then most likely you are doing it right, Outlook is not the result of code issue